# Using a custom CSS file - hiding a button

Tags: magento2, css

I created a local.css file that works well with this content:

```
body {
    background: blue;
}
```

However, I want to use it to hide this button:

```
<button type="submit" title="Add to Cart" class="action tocart primary"><span>Add to Cart</span></button>
```

How do I format the CSS to hide this button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can hide that button by `local.css` by the following rule:

```
.action.primary.tocart {
    display: none;
}
```

If it does not work, add `!important` to the property value:

```
.action.primary.tocart {
    display: none !important;
}
```